# Android NullPointerException in custom view access

Tags: android, android-layout, nullpointerexception, custom-view

I have created a custom view name **StepView** . Here is the code for StepView.

```
public class StepView extends LinearLayout {

    private Context cont;
    private LinearLayout stepHolder;

    public StepView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.stepview, this, true);
        stepHolder = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.stepHolder);

        cont = context;
    }

    public void addStep(String title, int drawableId, View.OnClickListener stepAction){

        View step = LayoutInflater.from(cont).inflate(R.layout.step, this, true);
        TextView txtText = (TextView) step.findViewById(R.id.txtText);
        ImageView imgStep = (ImageView) step.findViewById(R.id.imgStep);

        txtText.setText(title);
        imgStep.setImageResource(drawableId);

        stepHolder.addView(step);
    }


}
```

It is the code for stepview.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/stepHolder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

step.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imgStep"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtText">

    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Now I used the XML in main layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
 ..................
     </LinearLayout>

    <com.orthokeys.view.StepView
        android:id="@+id/stepMenu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </com.orthokeys.view.StepView>

</merge>
```

I have cheched that it is appearing properly. But when I add the following code it is giving NullPointerException.

```
StepView stepMenu = (StepView) findViewById(R.id.stepMenu);
stepMenu.addStep("Picture", R.drawable.step01, null);
```

I have checked that `stepMenu` is giving null.

Whatis the problem in my code?

Comment: What is your `step.xml` layout?  I want say from what you've given that it can't find "txtText" `TextView` and/or "imgStep" `ImageView` because it's not inflating properly.

Comment: I see nothing obviously wrong; can you try to clean and rebuild your project (or throw away your generated R class)?

Comment: "I have checked that `stepMenu` is giving null." Does that mean it *is* null, or you checked it and it's *not* null?

Comment: if(stepMenu==null)
 Log.d("stepMenu", "stepMenu is null");

Comment: I am getting that it is null.

Comment: are you calling `setContentView` with the correct activity layout?

Comment: No, I have called the setContentView(R.layout.main_layout); properly, not only that, I can access other Views in the layout and work with them.

Answer (score 3):

I solved the prob...change the code in constructor of StepView Class

```
public StepView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
  super(context, attrs);
  ....................
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not showing the full code block where you get the error, but it looks like you may have forgotten to use `setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);` to set the layout in use.

Comment: No, I have called the setContentView(R.layout.main_layout); properly, not only that, I can access other Views in the layout and work with them.

Comment: Add the stack trace to see what methods were called when the null point occured.