# NullPointerException when accessing RelativeLayout from a custom view

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, fragment, android-relativelayout, findviewbyid

I am relatively new to Android and am completely stuck on how to access my programmatically-defined Relative Layout (defined in a fragment) in my custom View.

In the fragment, this is what I have:

```
...
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container,false);
    RelativeLayout rl1 = new RelativeLayout(view.getContext());
    TextView tView1 = new TextView(view.getContext()); 
    tView1.setText("test");
    rl1.addView(tView1); 
    rl1.setId(1);
    tView1.setId(2);
...
}
```

Then in the custom view I call the relative Layout and TextView by id. When I try to do anything, I get a NullPointer exception.

```
...
RelativeLayout rl1 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(1);
TextView tView1 = (TextView) findViewById(2);
tView1.getText();
```

The code above shows trying to `.getText()` on the TextView, but anything I do to the RelativeLayout also causes a NullPointer exception.

So basically, it looks like I'm not finding the RelativeLayout and TextViews correctly.
FYI, I've already seen [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12915856/android-nullpointerexception-in-custom-view-access), but it didn't apply here, my constructors are already set up appropriately.

Comment: Ok, I've added more of the code. Can you give me the specific command/file type to add it to? Is it something like `view.addView(rl1)`? Or do I add this to the .xml file for Fragment1?

Comment: See my answer below. If you want to keep this dynamic, xml isn't really involved besides the initial inflation of the fragment layout. As I wrote, you need to cast into a layout since `addView()` is undefined for the `View` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be adding the Layout to the main View, however, you need to cast it first into a Layout:

```
YourLayout view = (YourLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container,false);
RelativeLayout rl1 = new RelativeLayout(view.getContext());
TextView tView1 = new TextView(view.getContext()); 
tView1.setText("test");
rl1.addView(tView1); 
rl1.setId(1);
tView1.setId(2);
view.addView (rl1);//add rl1 to the main View
```

Then to access, if you're working outside `onCreateView()` *and* [`onCreateView()` has already been called:](http://developer.android.com/images/fragment_lifecycle.png)

```
RelativeLayout rl1 = (RelativeLayout) getView().findViewById(1);
TextView tView1 = (TextView) rl1.findViewById(2);
tView1.getText();
```

If you're still trying to access the views in `onCreateView()`, `findViewById()` doesn't matter - you already have the references of your Views so use those.

It's also worth noting that adding listeners and such in `onCreateView()` to update the UI can be done, so you may be able to simply things a bit.

Comment: You've straightened things out for me very nicely! Can't tell you how much time I've wasted on this...

Answer (score 1):

You have to add your Relative layout to your layout group... And from the parent view of your layout you can access your relative layout and its childs